# How to find a corner by two points?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got an axis that contains 3 points. which one of them is in the center, and the other are in their corners. I have the position of the B and C, and i need to find A. How can i do that?

That's a preview of my current axis with their positions (Ignore that it's out of prespective):

[image: axis]

What can I do in order to find the B point?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If $B$ is twice as far from $A$ as $C$ is, then the difference in coordinates is twice as large in each direction.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: But wait, If i've got only point and a half. for instance: C(1,4) B(?, 1) C(?, ?).

Comment: If you only have three coordinates you don't have enough information.  Each dimension gives you an equation, so you have two equations.  You can determine two, but not three, unknowns.  Your original problem had two, so can be solved.

Comment: And if I've got only 2 unknowns. for instance: A(-4, ?) C(-1, 4) B(? ,1)

Comment: You can write $B_x-A_x=2(C_x-A_x)$ and similarly for $y$.  As long as there is only one unknown in each axis, you are fine.  If not, not.

Comment: I truly adore you! You've saved my day! Thanks again!